# Scale image layer uniformly using python-fu in Gimp

Tags: python, gimp, script-fu, python-fu, gimpfu

My goal is scaling an image using python-fu library for gimp in a uniform way. It means specifying width/height should be enough for scaling. Gimp should change height/width accordingly.

In Gimp GUI it's set with the marked toggle:

[image]

I'm using the following line to scale images

```
pdb.gimp_layer_scale(visibleLayer, 435, 100, True)
```

Which scales the layer to specified width and height.

Couldn't another way to do it uniformly as specified above.

Answer (score 0):

Used the following code to calculate target height to scale to and it worked.

```
def calculateHeight(logoLayer):
        if logoLayer.width < TARGET_LAYER_WIDTH:
            return round(logoLayer.height * (TARGET_LAYER_WIDTH * 1.0 / logoLayer.width))
        return logoLayer.height
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the same aspect ratio, you just do some math:

```
newHeight = oldHeight * ( newWidth / oldWidth )
```

or in slow-motion

- when you define a new width, this defines an enlargement factor equal to `newWidth / oldWidth`
- then you apply that enlargment factor to the height using the formula above.